# Getting an error: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass when trying to use a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that is the `index` method of another controller and I'm trying to add a form to the page, however I'm getting an error

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm fairly certain is has something to do with my routing, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where the error is occurring.

Here's the view with the form

```
<% @song_ranks.each do |song_rank| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= song_rank.title %></td>
    <td style="padding-left: 15px;"><%= song_rank.artist %></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><%= song_rank.ranknum %></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 35px;">
    <td> <%= render 'layouts/songrankform', song_rank: @song_rank %> </td>

    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

here's the method in the controller

```
  def updaterank
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song_rank.update(song_rank_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @band_song, alert: 'Song has been ranked.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @band_song }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @band_song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end
```

Here's my routes.rb file

```
  resources :band_songs do
    post 'upvote', to: 'band_songs#upvote'
    post 'band_songs_action'
    post 'updaterank', to: 'band_songs#updaterank'
  end
```

The form is actually part of a different model that I copied over to this view

There is a model for this partial form and a different model for the view and controller that Im putting the form into. So, what I'm trying to do is have the form in another view save to the other model.

Comment: looks like @band_song is not defined. Where do you initialize it? maybe in before_action, or in update method initilalize it

Comment: `@band_song` is actually the other view/controller that I'm attempting to put the `song_rank` form into. The answer below is allowing me to now create new records when I submit the form, but I need it to update the existing record, which Im having an issue doing

Comment: you cannot use variables from other controllers/actions. Imagine that you have just one entry point is your action. And all variables could be initialized only there. So they could be used in your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question seems like you didn't initialize `@song_rank` in index action.

You are not passing form object properly. Try change

```
<td> <%= render 'layouts/songrankform', song_rank: @song_rank %> </td>
```

to

```
<td> <%= render 'layouts/songrankform', song_rank: song_rank %> </td>
```

Because in your loop `song_rank` is right object not `@song_rank`

Comment: Would it be `SongRank.update` in order to update the existing record? The form submits right now but it creates a new record instead of updating the existing record